# Dial an extension using DTMF tones after a pause / Twilio Studio

Tags: twilio

I've been enjoying Studio, but I can't seem to find an answer on how to dial a number, pause, and dial an extension .... is that possible...  I looked for DTMF tones in Liquid but found nothing....

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

This is something that you can do with the REST API by sending [the `SendDigits` parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call#parameters-1) when making an outbound call. Or when connecting a call with TwiML using [`<Number>` and the `sendDigits` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number#attributes-sendDigits).

I don't believe you can do this in Studio yet though.